# Compare two path in TCL

Tags: compare, tcl, matching

I have a path in Linux /home/probil/xilinxip/pll1.xci in the the file which is getting read. Now I want to compare this this path with all the path present in that file and if it matches then print file is there in file.
File is having many paths in the similar format. If I am using if statement it is giving error.

```
set xci_source_files_ip [file normalize "$origin_dir/xci_source_files.f"]
set xci_source [open $xci_source_files_ip r]

while {[gets $xci_source file] > -1} {
set file $file
set file [file normalize $file]
#if{[$file] eq ["/home/probil/xilinxip/pll1.xci"]}{
   puts "file matched"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Filenames should be compared as simple strings (typically after normalization, though there are cases where you don't want to do that). Thus, you do this:

```
if {$file eq $file2} {
    puts "They're the same thing!"
}
```

Or, with normalization:

```
if {[file normalize $file] eq [file normalize $file2]} {
    puts "They're the same thing!"
}
```

If you're comparing against a constant that you know is a normalized filename already, you can omit doing the explicit normalize (but the filename literal needs to go in double quotes or braces inside an expression, as part of expression syntax):

```
if {$file eq "/home/probil/xilinxip/pll1.xci"} {
    puts "They're the same thing!"
}
```

```
if {[file normalize $file] eq "/home/probil/xilinxip/pll1.xci"} {
    puts "They're the same thing!"
}
```

**Don't put them in square brackets by themselves** though (`if {[$file1] eq ["..."]}`) as square brackets are for *command* substitutions in Tcl; you end up trying to call a command with a rather strange name, which doesn't (usually) work!